# interpreting the standard errors from a simple linear model

Tags: anova, linear-model, interpretation

I am having a basic doubt about the interpretation of the standard errors from the R output of a linear model in which you have a single explanatory categorical variable.

Let's say we are using the `iris` dataset in R and we are modeling the relationship between `Sepal.Length` and `Species`, so we have the following:

```
m1<-lm(iris$Sepal.Length~iris$Species)

summary(m1)
```

which gives:

```
Call:
lm(formula = iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Species)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.6880 -0.3285 -0.0060  0.3120  1.3120 

Coefficients:
                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)              5.0060     0.0728  68.762  < 2e-16 ***
iris$Speciesversicolor   0.9300     0.1030   9.033 8.77e-16 ***
iris$Speciesvirginica    1.5820     0.1030  15.366  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.5148 on 147 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6187,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6135 
F-statistic: 119.3 on 2 and 147 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Species has 3 levels (setosa, versicolor and virginica) and I know that for the estimate the `(Intercept)` gives me the estimate for setosa (5.0060) and that for the other species the estimate value shown is the difference to the setosa estimate, so their values would be 5.0060+0.9300 for versicolor and 5.0060+1.5820 for virginica.

Now, I would like to report the std. error for these estimates. So can I simply take the standard error that is shown for each species (e.g. versicolor:5.936+/-0.1030), or are these std. errors for the difference and I would have to sum the `(Intercept)` error to get the error for versicolor or virginica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5.0060+0.9300 is the estimate of mean of $Y$ for versicolor. you are correct. But its variance is $0.0728^2+0.1030^2 +2\times \text{Cov(two estimates)}$. So you need to find Covariance between them. Then square root of variance is the standard error. the same for virginica.

Another tricky method: Fit another model by replacing "versicolor" with "aversicolor" in the data, you get the answer for versicolor. I think you know how to get answers for virginica following the same way.

Comment: great, I will try your later suggestion. simply changing the baseline factor level with `relevel()`, as described in http://tinyurl.com/owsjkof, should do it.

Comment: when I change the reference level for `Species`, the `std. error` value always stays the same. I don't think I am doing anything wrong, would you know why this is the case?

Comment: sample size in each group are equal?

Comment: yes, they are the same

Comment: Then they should be the same. If not same, your statistical software would be problem. If you want, you can delete some of the data to make the sample sizes are unequal among groups, and you should get different SEs.